# Parsing XML - Value out of range

Tags: c#, xml, tfs, windows-8.1

I have a problem, I am trying to list all my tfs projects and I am having this exception:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

Here is my method

```
public async  Task<XElement> Deserialize()
{
    string xml = "https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Projects('xxxx')/WorkItems";
    var feed = await this.GetAsync(PROJECTS_PATH);

    var x = feed.Items.ToString();
    XElement dataTfs = new XElement(x);
    foreach(var tfsdata in feed.Items) 
    {

    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(tfsdata.Content.Text);
    IEnumerable<XElement> elem = xDoc.Elements();

    XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
    XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

    var data =  from query in xDoc.Descendants(m + "properties")
               select new TfsEntities.Models.TfsEntities.properties
               {
                   Title = (string)query.Element(d + "Title"),
                   State = (string)query.Element(d + "State"),
                   Reason = (string)query.Element(d + "Reason")
               };
    dataTfs.Add(data.ToList());
    }
    return (XElement)dataTfs;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem please?
Thank you

Comment: At which line does the exception occur?

Comment: It appears here  eventHandler(this, new ObservableDictionaryChangedEventArgs(change, key)); in the ObservableDictionary class

Comment: Let me rephrase that: At which line in the code above does the exception occur?

Comment: At the last line, maybe it's a cast issue, I returned earlier one project (item[0]) but I have troubles to return the list

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that the exception occurs on `return (XElement) dataTfs;`. There is no casting going on there since `dataTfs` is declared as `XElement`.